# SQL Server Express: User Instance Issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

Greetings – To automate testing of our database SPROCs, we’ve been using dynamically created databases inside of a User Instance.  This has been working very well – the build server and, until very recently, all the developers could all run the tests.  However, one of our developer machines is now returning the following error when we try to connect to the user instance:

> Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server due to a failure in
>   starting the process for the user
>   instance. The connection will be
>   closed.

Here is what the log file says:

> 2008-12-04 10:46:29.77 Logon
>   Error: 15372, Severity: 16, State: 1.
>   2008-12-04 10:46:29.77 Logon
>   Failed to generate a user instance of
>   SQL Server due to a failure in
>   starting the process for the user
>   instance. The connection will be
>   closed. [CLIENT: ]

**What I’ve done to fix it so far**

- Deleted C:\Documents and Settings[username]\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data
- Changed SQL Service to run as “Local System” instead of “Network Service”
- Uninstalled SQL Express, deleted ALL data directories (e.g. “MSSQL.1”), and reinstalled SQL Express

None of these “fixes” have fixed the problem.  It used to work on the machine in question, and we would like not to have to repave it.

Please help!!!

Thanks - Jordan

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I tried all of the above fixes again, and then I restarted the entire system and it appears to work.  Strange!  I had restarted my system in the past, but it looks like you have to apply these fixes first and then restart.  I think I'll try switching the service back to logging in as Network Service.

Thanks - Jordan

Answer (score 0):

I found the same issue on my azure VM. Then I opened the SQL Server Configuration Manager, opened SQL Server Network Configuration, -Protocols for  and found that "Named Pipes" and "TCP/IP" were disabled. I enabled them, and the error went away.